# Change all CUDA functions to __host__ __device__

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I want to use an exist function in CUDA, but it contains many class and other functions.
Adding `__host__ __device__` before every function is trivial. So, is there an automatic method to do this? Or how to let nvcc compile all functions as `__device__ __host__`?

Comment: In a word, no there isn't an automatic way to do this. But as you yourself point out, it is trivial to decorate the functions you need with \_\_device\_\_, so what is the problem?

Comment: OK... I think I may write one to do this...

Comment: If there are many existing classes and functions, it might be better to revise them and create a GPU specific solution, instead of making everything `__device__`.

Comment: I think this is a silly limitation of `nvcc`. I understand that functions compiled to object code need to know their target code. But inline functions or functions that are compiled on demand (on instantiation), like member functions or template functions should automatically be `__device__` and/or `__host__` if the are called as such and also can be (SFINAE-like) compiled as such. I think the current situation is crazy and I cannot wait until some nvcc wrapper or nvcc or clang does it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, GPU programming is all about massive parallelism. It is a totally different paradigm than normal single threaded programming.
Unless you just want to apply these functions at the same time to individual elements of large arrays, there is no benefit of coding it into the GPU.
In fact, GPU core clock is much slower than your processor.
If you will compile functions written mainly targeting a CPU in a single thread flavor to GPU, you will get a potential performance penalty.
You need to re-think your problem into the GPU paradigm.

Comment: You may right generally.But in fact its about meachine learning,I use min-max-modular to parallel the data so it can train parallelly without changing the algorthim,and I have a way to integrate the results. It should be run in multiCPU rather than GPU. But for some reason,I have no choice..